# How to use Opencv in C ( Gcc )

Tags: c, opencv

*Hi.*
my problme is in the Opencv Library
how can i use the Opencv Module in C coding Language ?
Is this library for Python , C# and C++ only?
can I use it in C ?
how can i downloaded it for C language in GCC Compiler ?

I use the Gnu/Linux Fedora

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/12/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada,go,d,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-12.1.1-20220507/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-offload-defaulted --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-cet --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto --enable-link-serialization=1
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 12.1.1 20220507 (Red Hat 12.1.1-1) (GCC)
```

Comment: opencv is written in c++, and gcc will handle that just fine, so why C ?

Comment: Curious: why do you want to use C? Is using C++ (possibly with C-like or even C-compatible C++ code only) an option? Typically the only reason to want it for C would be so small (embedded) system, that you can't fit C++ standard library there...

Comment: Anyway, search for "OpenCV C bindings". They exist, but not sure if maintained.

Comment: look into OpenVX. that's a different library. -- or write `extern "C"` functions (C++) that use OpenCV and are themselves callable from C code.

Comment: very thanks . I love the C coding Language.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dnf install opencv-devel
```

It will install opencv
then here is the sample code from my own project

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

// Global variables
int camera_isOpen = 1;
int screen_width, screen_height;



void capturePhoto(cv::VideoCapture cap) {
    cv::Mat frame;
    if (cap.read(frame)) {
        // Save the photo with a unique name
        std::string filename = "captured_photo" +    
std::to_string(time(NULL)) + ".jpg";
        cv::imwrite(filename, frame);
        printf("Photo captured and saved as '%s'\n", filename.c_str());
    } else {
        printf("Error: Could not capture photo.\n");
    }
}

void showPreview(cv::VideoCapture cap) {

    while (camera_isOpen) {
        // Capture a frame from the camera
        cv::Mat frame;
        cap.read(frame);

        if (frame.empty()) {
            printf("Error: Could not read frame.\n");
            break;
        }

        // Flip the frame horizontally to prevent mirroring
        cv::flip(frame, frame, 1);

        // Display the frame in the full-screen window with image scaling
        cv::namedWindow("Camera Feed", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
        cv::setWindowProperty("Camera Feed", cv::WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, 
cv::WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
        cv::resizeWindow("Camera Feed", screen_width, screen_height);  // 
Resize the window


        cv::imshow("Camera Feed", frame);

        // Check for the 'q' key press to exit the loop
        int key = cv::waitKey(1);
        if (key == 'q') {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void openCamera() {
    // Open the default camera (usually the built-in webcam)
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0, cv::CAP_V4L2);

    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        printf("Error: Could not open camera.\n");
        return;
    }

    // Get the screen's width and height
    screen_width = (int)cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    screen_height = (int)cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);

    // Create a named window and set it to full-screen mode
    cv::namedWindow("Camera Feed", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cv::setWindowProperty("Camera Feed", cv::WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, 
cv::WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);

    // Show the camera preview
    showPreview(cap);

    // Release the camera and close the OpenCV window
    cap.release();
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
}

void closeCamera() {
    // Release the camera and close the OpenCV window
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
    cv::VideoCapture(0).release();
}
```

g++ myProject.c -o myProject `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`